# inverse of a list python [(160,177),(198,123)]

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

`[(160, 177), (162, 169), (163, 169), (166, 173), (166, 176), (166, 177), (169, 176), (169, 177)]`

I want the inverse of this list, so it becomes:

`[(177, 160), (169, 162), (169, 163), (173, 166), (176, 166), (177, 166), (176, 169), (177, 169)]`

I think you can do something like `list1[:-1]` or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion it's cleaner to reverse the pairs explicitly:

```
[(snd, fst) for fst, snd in thelist]
```

Comment: Even though it's not mentioned.. I'm guessing the OP might have more items in real case scenario

Answer (score 4):

```
a=[(160, 177), (162, 169), (163, 169), (166, 173), (166, 176), (166, 177), (169, 176), (169, 177)]
b=[e[::-1] for e in a]
print b
```

Runnable code in this Bunk - http://codebunk.com/bunk#-It1THfMsVDWUQMq8eRT

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using `map` and `reversed` but prefer the [list comprehension based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16222146/846892) 
in this case as it requires only a single loop compared to 2 in `map` version.

```
In [24]: lis=[(160, 177), (162, 169), (163, 169), (166, 173), (166, 176), (166, 177), (169, 176), (169, 177)]

In [26]: map(tuple,map(reversed,lis))  #use itertools.imap for large lists
Out[26]: 
[(177, 160),
 (169, 162),
 (169, 163),
 (173, 166),
 (176, 166),
 (177, 166),
 (176, 169),
 (177, 169)]
```

Comment: I was just about to post this but I was afraid since everyone criticizes `map` as not "Pythonic".  This is what it's made for.

Comment: @squiguy who says `map` is unpythonic? The advantage of map is that it is directly [compiled into C code](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops). Though in above case it is going to be slow compared to LC version due to two loops.

Comment: "map" isn't "unpythonic", it's just a pre-3 way of writing a list comprehension, which produces the same code. `map(f,list)` is just `[f(x) for x in list]`, which is clearer.

Comment: I +1 your answer.  Just everyone loves list comprehensions and not functional programming.

Comment: Although `map` is pythonic in many situations, in this case it is less readable and I believe it will also be slower